# Summation of three dependent variables with a given constraint

Tags: summation

Find the  minimum and maximum value of $\sum_{i,j,k} ({x_{ij} + x_{ik} + x_{jk}})$ given that $\sum_{i,j} {x_{ij}} = 225$ and $1\leq i<j<k \leq50$

> My approach : i tried fixing k and getting the sum of ij term but that is not forming any pattern anyhow , next i tried making all possible combinations so that in that i can use the sum contraint given but that is not easy as we would need to plot in 3D , so is there a elegant approach for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you sum the three pairs across all triples, each pair appears $50-2=48$ times, so
$$\sum_{i,j,k} (x_{ij} + x_{ik} + x_{jk}) = 48 \sum_{i,j} x_{ij} = 48 \cdot 225 = 10800.$$
That is, the minimum and maximum are both equal to $10800$.

In the [linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4414927/finding-the-minimum-and-maximum-number-of-connected-triangles-according-to-given), this sum is not what is being minimized or maximized.

An equivalent way to think about it: in a complete graph on $50$ nodes, how many triangles contain edge $\{i,j\}$?  One for each other node $k\not\in\{i,j\}$.

Comment: I see in that linked one then what will the minimum value be , the OP said it to be 600 @RobPratt as such when i did that i got negative value which doesnt makes sense at all for minimum